# How to remove outer line of panel grid major outer line from radar plot?

Tags: ggplot2, radar-chart

I have worked with radar plot by using ggplot.
I would like to remove the outermost line of the panel grid (i.e.,part of the theme).

Since I want all the points to connect with a straight line. I used fuction as follows:

```r
coord_radar <- function (theta = "x", start = 0, direction = 1) {
  theta <- match.arg(theta, c("x", "y"))
  r <- if (theta == "x") "y" else "x"
  ggproto("CordRadar", CoordPolar, theta = theta, r = r, start = start, 
          direction = sign(direction),
          is_linear = function(coord) TRUE)
}
```

I found a post on StackOverflow. To avoid the outermost line, I should use

```
geom_hline(yintercept = seq(0, 10, by = 1), colour = "darkgray", size = 0.35,show.legend = TRUE).
```

However, I can not use `coord_radar` together with `geom_hline`.
I need suggestions regarding my issue: I want to connect the points with a straight line and no outermost line of major panel grid on my plot.
Thanks

```
#data
a <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
b <- c(6,7,8,2,3,4,9,10)
c <- data.frame(a,b)

#function for connecting points with strighted line
coord_radar <- function (theta = "x", start = 0, direction = 1) {
  theta <- match.arg(theta, c("x", "y"))
  r <- if (theta == "x") "y" else "x"
  ggproto("CordRadar", CoordPolar, theta = theta, r = r, start = start, 
          direction = sign(direction),
          is_linear = function(coord) TRUE)
}

#ggplot
p <- ggplot(data = c ,aes(x = a, y = b))
#p <- p + geom_hline(yintercept = seq(0, max(cal_p$up), by = 1), colour = "darkgray", size = 0.35,show.legend = TRUE)
p <- p + scale_y_continuous(breaks  = seq(0, 10,by=1))
p <- p + coord_radar()
p <- p + theme_bw()
p <- p + theme(panel.border = element_blank())
p <- p + theme(axis.title.x = element_blank())
p <- p + theme(axis.title.y = element_blank())
p <- p + theme(axis.text.y  = element_blank())
p <- p + theme(axis.ticks.y  = element_blank())
p <- p + geom_polygon(fill = NA, colour = "purple")  
p <- p + geom_point()
p <- p + annotate("text", x = 0.5, y = 0:10, label = c("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"), color="darkgray")
p
```